# Custom layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create the following design [image]

I sort of did it by using `PercentRelativeLayout` for layouts and `AutoResizeTextView` for those TextViews, but I ended up with over 10 layouts and I can see that the layout is very slow being rendered. The main problem were the images because I could get them to do what I want only by doing this sort of things:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonright1layout"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:layout_heightPercent="40%">

                        <name.company.newapp.PostForm.SelectPhoto.SquareRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/btnright2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/me" />
                        </name.company.newapp.PostForm.SelectPhoto.SquareRelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Could anyone suggest a better approach?

Update:

The loading was caused by a large drawable that I had as a background. I removed it and now it's working fine.Since this thread is here I have a few questions about this design:

1. Will there be any problems if I don't set the size of the TextViews/set it in `sp` ?(`textSize`)

   `<TextView
                           android:id="@+id/date_time"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                           android:text="Text4"
                           android:textColor="#fff" />`
2. Will there be any problems if I set the size of the ImageViews in `dp` ?

   `<ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/img_5"
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/img_size"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/img_size"
                       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                       android:background="@drawable/nexticn" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem if you don't specify `textSize` for `TextView`. Default value is used.

You can set `ImageView` width and height in dp without problems. In such case it would be useful to specify a value for `scaleType` attribute for preventing images to be rendered in a bad way.

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:layout_weight` is what you're after

Comment: I started with that, but those weights could never do what I asked them. And I had to use a lot of layouts.